# Unable to Modify Azure DevOps Project "Process". I just provisioned a free cloud server instance. I am an admin

Tags: process, permissions, devops, settings, admin

I just created a new Azure DevOps cloud/instance.  I am the project admin, but I am unable to update the Organization Settings -> "Process".  When I try to add a custom field into a work item or try to change the "States", It seems I don't have the permission to do so.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I created a Process that inherited the default Process.  Then I changed the Process for the Project.  Poof, now I can make changes to my Project's Process, e.g. add new work item types.